ListBox child element filling
       <ListBox x:Name="myData"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Background="{StaticResource TransparentColor}" Grid.Row="1"
           BorderBrush="{StaticResource LeftGridColor}"  >
           <ListBox.Resources>
               <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollViewer}" />
               <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollBarMinimal}" />
               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dto:DownLoadDto}">
                   <Grid Background="{StaticResource ThemeColor}">
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding index}" />
                       </Grid>
                       <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                           <WrapPanel >
                               <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="40"/>
                               <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Des}" />
                               </StackPanel>
                           </WrapPanel>
                       </Grid>
                       <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" />
                       </Grid>
                       <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                           <Path Data="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z " Fill="Red"  Stroke="Red"  Stretch="Fill"  Width="16" Height="16"/>
                       </Grid>
                       <Grid Grid.Column="4">
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.Resources>
        
       </ListBox>

I wish the content in the Datatemple would be filled in the proportion I set but in fact they are very close together. This problem annoys me very much and I would love to get your answer
I try to set up HorizontalContentAlignment = "Stretch" the result is close together

This is what I would expect:

This style uses a fixed width, I want the style to be proportional to the swing

You need to update the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle to horizontally stretch the Content Presenter.
<ListBox x:Name="myData">
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <!--*** THIS GUY ***-->
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBoxItem>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="1" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <WrapPanel>
                <Rectangle Fill="LightGray"
                           Width="40" 
                           Height="40"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="NAME" />
                    <TextBlock Text="DES" />
                </StackPanel>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Text="ALBUM" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="3">
            <Path Data="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z "
                  Fill="Red"
                  Stroke="Red"
                  Stretch="Fill"
                  Width="16"
                  Height="16" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="4">
            <TextBlock Text="SIZE" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>


Set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on the ListBox is enough. No need to change the ItemContainerStyle.

Oh hey, what do you know! You are right.

Thank you for your answer, which allowed me to solve this problem
